# Placing existing textboxes into a toolbar

Tags: vb.net, textbox, toolbar

I was wondering if there is any way to place existing text boxes into a toolbar in Visual Basic 2010. These text boxes are also linked to a database.

I need a way to have the textboxes on display when any tabpage is selected, therefore I thought perhaps having them in a toolbar above the tab bar would be a solution to the problem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not how about a panel aligned on top of form. You can position the top of the TabControl wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you, this works well as an alternative to having them in a toolbar.